# How to send parameters to assets file webview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to open my index.html in the assets folder but with parameters, I tried to open like this:
initialFile: "assets/index.html?name=foo&lastname=Bar" but it doesn´t work.

> ```
> return Container(
>       child: InAppWebView(
>         //initialFile: "assets/index.html",
>         initialOptions: inAppWebViewGroupOptions,
>         initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
>             url: Uri.parse("file:///assets/index.html"),
>             method: 'GET',
>             body:
>                 Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode("name=foo&lastname=Bar")),
>             headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can just set WebView cookie to pass paramerters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [In-App Localhost Server](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/5.x.x/in-app-localhost-server).